# Como atribuir o retorno de um forEach a uma variável

Tags: javascript, foreach, axios

Olá! tenho a seguinte situação, recebo como retorno de um get a uma api um array de objetos, para obter os dados que preciso uso um forEach.

esse e o get:

```
 getData = async ( ) => { 
    const response = await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
    const data = response.data
    return data
    }
```

Esse e o ForEach que estou usando:

```
     getData().then(data => { 
        data.forEach(element => {
        name = [element.name.common];
        console.log(name); // aqui recebo todos os itens selecionados.
        });

        console.log(name); // aqui recebo [ 'Greenland' ], esse é o primeiro item do array.
       })
```

Quando acesso a variável fora do forEach tenho como retorno apenas o primeiro item. Como consigo atribuir todo o retorno a uma variável acessível fora do forEach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quer guardar múltiplos valores sob uma mesma referência pode usar um [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).
Array é um tipo de dado que representa uma coleção de elementos associados a um índice numérico inteiro. É semelhante a listas e pode ser alterado a qualquer momento.
O método [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adiciona um ou mais elementos ao final de um array.

Um reparo imediato para o seu código seria declarar um Array antes do laço de iteração e durante a iteração ir preenchendo o array declarado:

```js
const getData = async() => {
  return (await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")).data;
};

getData().then(data => {
  const names = [];             //Declara um Array onde serão armazenados os nomes dos países.
  data.forEach(e => {
    names.push(e.name.common);  //Adiciona ao final do array names o nome do país.
  });
  console.log(names);           
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

No seu caso específico essa não é a melhor das abordagens pois a resposta de `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all` já é um Array possibilitando a aplicação direto de uma função de transformação para cada elemento da resposta com o método [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
O método `Array.prototype.map()` invoca uma função callback passada por argumento a cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.

No seu exemplo apenas passe para `Array.prototype.map()` uma função retornando o nome de cada país:

```js
const getData = async() => {
  return (await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")).data;
};

getData().then(data => {
  const names = data.map(e => e.name.common);  //Para cada elemento da resposta retorne a propriedade name.common.
  console.log(names);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```